# Imagemagick-stream in docker: convert ENOENT

Tags: meteor, server, imagemagick, docker-compose, enoent

I am working on a Meteor project where I am using imagemagick-stream to create thumbnails from uploaded images. When testing this with the `meteor` command, it works just fine but when I build the server for production and run it using docker-compose, I get

```
Error: spawn convert ENOENT
```

I suspect this happens because of docker's containers which don't allow access to `convert`. How can I make docker allow the call to `convert`?

Comment: What docker base image are you building on? The `FROM` statement in the Dockefile(s).

Comment: A full example (e.g. a minimal Dockerfile to reproduce), and the output of `docker version` and `docker info` would help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was actually fairly easy to do:
I just had to add

```
apt-get update
apt-get install -y imagemagick
```

to my dockerfile.